# Restrict view item to the person created the item and to "Assigned To"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list that is configured so that only the person who created an item can see and edit it (I can't see somebody else's entries). I have a column "Assigned To" which is a person lookup. I want the person specified in that field be able to see the entry even though he didn't create it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: What have you tried? What tools are you using? You will have to manage per-item permissions programmatically.